# Shrink and steal the moon

Tags: technology

Can the moon be shrunk to the size of a tennis ball and change the weight to be lighter to take it back to earth?

Comment: Are you specifically asking for the type of technology to use to shrink the moon, or if such an act is feasible?

Comment: No, it cannot. Next!

Comment: You will be put under arrested for the violation of the 1967 Outer Space Treaty, I presumed you must succeeded in the heist to be charged 

Comment: which moon?  Not the big one made of cheese right? Someone will notice when the billions of people die from the tides changing and the massive earth quakes.

Comment: If you're a Time Lord...*maybe*. If you're anything short of a Time Lord, no.

Answer (score 4):

## Shrinking

This one is simple, simply exert a lot of inward force pressure, such as external pressure or internal gravity pull. At the size of a tennis ball, the Moon would still be way larger than her Schwarzschild's radius (for comparison, Earth's would be around the size of a coin).

As for how to exert that force, well, you could put a few cans of neutron star core inside the Moon's core for a few minutes. You will need to scoop it up carefully later.

## Make it lighter

You will need [negative mass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/394406/negative-mass-in-spacetime-fabric), but that has its own problem in the form of the [runaway motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass). TL;DR: the Moon would spontaneously accelerate to the speed of light, with all the physics law breaking that ensues.